# Usage of inb, inl, inw to access kernel space from user space

Tags: drivers, kernel, programming

Could you please give me some user space examples of using inb, inl, inw to access kernel space in ubuntu?

/Kanu

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6033/9812

Answer (score 1):

These functions (or macros) are defined in `<asm/io.h>`. You need to tell gcc to `-O`ptimise the code for them to be inlined (I think).

For their usage, type

```
man inw
```

Makelinux.net also has a [guide](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-2.shtml) on how to use them.

I can't give you an example since it depends on the hardware you're using, but this should get you started.

If anyone is interested in it, there's also a [Python module, portio](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/portio/0.4), to provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To use IO port commands (in/out), you need to run as root and have reserved access via the ioperm() call: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ioperm

If this is `beep.c`:

```
/* Copyright 2011, Kees Cook <kees@outflux.net>, License: GPLv2 */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned char orig, bits;

   /* gain access to speaker control port */
   if (ioperm(0x61, 0x61, 1) < 0) {
       perror("0x61");
       return 1;
   }
   /* gain access to speaker frequency port */
   if (ioperm(0x42, 0x42, 1) < 0) {
       perror("0x42");
       return 2;
   }

   /* turn on speaker */
   orig = bits = inb(0x61);
   bits |= 3;
   outb(bits, 0x61);

   /* set 1000 Hz frequency */
   bits = 0xA9;
   outb(bits, 0x42);
   bits = 0x04;
   outb(bits, 0x42);

   /* listen to the beep */
   sleep(1);

   /* restore speaker bits to turn off speaker */
   outb(orig, 0x61);

   return 0;
}
```

$ make beep

$ sudo ./beep